# List number of occurrences for each record SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have two tables and I need to list the number of complaints by each rental number.
the tables I have are the following:

RENTAL TABLE

```
RENTAL_NO   RENTAL_DA   R   LEA     LEASE_STA   LEASE_END   STAFF   APT_NO
100101          12-MAY-07   O   One     01-JUN-07   31-MAY-08   SA200   201
100102          21-MAY-07   O   Six     01-JUN-07   30-NOV-07   SA220   102
100103      12-OCT-07   O   Six     01-NOV-07   30-APR-08   SA240   203
100104      06-MAR-08   O   One     01-APR-08   31-MAR-09   SA210   101
100105      15-APR-08   O   One     01-MAY-08   30-APR-09   SA220   104
100106      15-JUL-08   S   One     01-AUG-08   31-JUL-09   SA200   100
```

Complaints table

```
COMPLAINT_NO    COMPLAINT    RENTAL_COMPLAINT           APT_COMPLAINT  RENTAL_NO    APT_NO  S
10010           12-DEC-07    kitchen sink clogged       100103         203          F
10011           17-AUG-08    water heater not working   100105         104          F
10012           17-SEP-08    room heater problem        100105         104
10013           17-SEP-08    AC not working                            103
10014           20-OCT-08    car parking not proper     100103
10015           08-NOV-08    delay in payment           100104                      F
10016           16-NOV-08    utility not working                       202
```

===================================================================================
so I will need something like this:

```
apt_no       Number of complaints
10000         3
10100         1
.
.
.
```

Im still a newbie and I've been trying a lot and I dont seem to get it right. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should change the RENTAL_NO to APT_NO in your complaints table, so that it matches up with the rental table.

Answer (score 1):

try this out:

```
    select APT_COMPLAINT, count(complaint_no) as CComplaint
    from complaints
    group by APT_COMPLAINT
```

Answer (score 1):

With info you provided, I can only guess what are relations between your tables. But if `Compliants.APT_NO` is `FK` for `Rental.RENTAL_NO`, you gonna need this code

```
  SELECT r.RENTAL_NO apt_no, count(*) Number_of_complaints
    FROM Rental r JOIN Complaints c 
                       ON r.APT_NO = c.RENTAL_NO
GROUP BY r.APT_no
```

Comment: Yes I think apt_no from rentals table and rental_no from complaints table should match up.  Shouldn't there be an `as` between `count(*)` and `Number_of_complaints`?

Comment: @steinmas not necessarily. it would work without is as it would with it. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/31853). But, for correct ANSI sql it should be there, I believe